# Capture all products in Shopify collection

Tags: shopify, liquid

As I'm looping through a collection in Shopify, I want to add that product to another array of products so that I can loop through it again.

```
{% assign custom_products = '' %}
{% for product in collections['all'].products %}
    {% assign custom_products = custom_products | append: product %}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I iterate through it again I get nothing

```
{% for product in custom_products %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I dump `custom_products` I get `ProductDropProductDropProductDropProductDrop...` and so on. Is this because I am constructing as a string? I want the second `for` loop in the Liquid template to move through the products as if it were `collections['all'].products`. Any ideas?

Comment: Your example is not clear. You are looping through the all products collection, trying to duplicate it. Duplicating collections is best done using Shopify, not Liquid.

Comment: @DavidLazar I am conditionally appending products to the custom array. My question is how to maintain the format so that I can continue looping the my custom array down the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% capture custom_products %}
  {% for product in collections['all'].products %}
    {{ custom_products }},{{ product.handle }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign custom_products = custom_products | split: ',' %}

{% for product in custom_products %}
  {{ all_products[product].title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: all_products is limited to 20. Hard limit. So far. You never noticed?

Comment: @DavidLazar.. Yes. I'm aware of it. But for the query in question, this is the closest way I can think that can be implemented.